# Como agrupar por hora valores agrupados distinta fecha en un solo valor

Tags: python, csv, pandas

Buenas necesito mostrar la cantidad de llamados que se hacen a cada hora en un mes entero.
Hasta ahora pude hacer un resample del CSV para que me quede de la siguiente forma:

```
                     Cantidad
   Fecha
2017-03-01 00:00:00      5
2017-03-01 01:00:00      1
      .
      .
2017-03-31 22:00:00      7
2017-03-31 23:00:00      2
```

La fecha seria un datetimeIndex y agrupe todos los valores en intervalos de 1 hora.
Lo que necesito ahora es poder agrupar por hora a todas las filas sin importar el dia, es decir que me quede de esta forma, por ejemplo:

```
                     Cantidad
   Fecha
  2017-03  00:00:00     600
  2017-03  01:00:00     200
  2017-03  02:00:00      30
      .
      .
  2017-03  22:00:00     500
  2017-03  23:00:00     150
```

Busque en varios post y en la documentacion de pandas pero no pude ver nada que me pueda servir o que me dé el resultado esperado

Answer (score 1):

Si no he entendido mal necesitas agrupar por horas dentro de cada mes.

Para crear un ejemplo reproducible vamos a suponer que tenemos el siguiente csv de entrada llamado `agrupar_horas.csv`   y similar al ejemplo que muestras:

> Fecha,Cantidad
>   2017-03-01 00:00:00,1
>   2017-03-01 01:00:00,2
>   2017-03-01 22:00:00,3
>   2017-03-01 23:00:00,4
>   2017-03-02 00:00:00,1
>   2017-03-02 01:00:00,2
>   2017-03-02 22:00:00,3
>   2017-03-02 23:00:00,4
>   2017-04-01 00:00:00,5
>   2017-04-01 01:00:00,6
>   2017-04-01 22:00:00,7
>   2017-04-01 23:00:00,8
>   2017-04-02 00:00:00,5
>   2017-04-02 01:00:00,6
>   2017-04-02 22:00:00,7
>   2017-04-02 23:00:00,8

Para hacer lo que deseas si no me he confundido lo más parecido que se me ocurre es usando `groupby`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('agrupar_horas.csv', index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

periodo = df.index.to_period("M")
df2 = df.groupby([ periodo, df.index.time]).sum()

print(df2)
```

Salida:

> ```
>                   Cantidad
> Fecha                     
> 2017-03 00:00:00         2
>         01:00:00         4
>         22:00:00         6
>         23:00:00         8
> 2017-04 00:00:00        10
>         01:00:00        12
>         22:00:00        14
>         23:00:00        16
> ```